# not getting a sliding effect when loading images via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I need to load different images  from each section  and use  image slider for every section .

for Example : Sections Tabs : IT  - Information Security - Wed development ...etc .

Then when user click on any section will display images slider related to this section .

So I created that with Ajax .

homepage :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="newscript.js"></script>
    <link href="themes/2/js-image-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="themes/2/js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="generic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="rounded">
<img src="img/top_bg.gif" alt="top" /><div id="main" class="container">
    <ul id="navigation">
    <?php
       include("samiloxide.php");
       $sql=mysql_query(" select * from  section ");

       while($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
           echo "<li><a  onclick='loadpage($r[id])' >$r[section]</a></li>" ;
       }
    ?>

    <li><img id="loading" src="img/ajax_load.gif" alt="loading" /></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="clear"></div>        
    <div id="pageContent">
  </div>   
...........
```

JavaScript file :

```
    var section;
    function loadpage(section){ 
       var section = section.toString();      
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "get.php",
          dataType: "script",
          data: ({section : section}),
          success: function(html){
             $("#pageContent").empty();
             $("#pageContent").append(html);
          }
       });
     }

-------
```

get.php  file :

```
    <div id="sliderFrame">
        <div id="slider">

           <?php
        include("samiloxide.php");
        //if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

        $section = (int)$_POST['section'];

        $sql=mysql_query(" select * from images   where section='$section'");


        while($rr=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
           echo " <img src='$rr[image]' alt='text..' />";
                }
           ?>

        </div>
.....
```

Slider not work just load image without sliding effect !!  but if i call get.php from browser ...etc  it's work ??!! 
What's problem in my Ajax code?

Comment: where is the slider call function? you just added the script (js-image-slider.js) on the page?

Comment: I used this slider 
http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider

Answer (score 0):

This slider script does not seem to like/support dynamically generated img tags, and instead maps/binds to the ones present on DOMLoad.

When you are done inserting images in the DOM, call imageSlider.reload(). So, in your case, it'd be after the .html() call in the AJAX complete callback.

Comment: I know, my answer was completely related to it. In fact, I've got the source of it open right now :-)

This is the edit:
     success: function(html){
       $("#pageContent").empty();
       $("#pageContent").append(html);
       imageSlider.reload();
       }

P.S: the JS code is awful. I have no idea how they manage to sell this for $20.